# Phonegap / Cordova File Transfer Upload Image as Base64 String not working in ios

Tags: ios, file, cordova, base64

I'm working on uploading image as base64 image stream from phonegap/cordova application, it works perfectly fine in Android but not working in ios, however in ios it works when the image is as png/jpg but when it is as base64 image stream its not working, Please can anybody help me out with the same.

Here is my code for the same,

```
var options = new FileUploadOptions();
    options.fileKey = "file";   
    options.fileName = "test.jpg";
    options.mimeType = "image/jpeg";    
    options.chunkedMode = false;

     options.params = {
                "key": "test.jpg",
                "AWSAccessKeyId": awsKey,
                "acl": acl,
                "policy": policyBase64,
                "signature": signature,
                "Content-Type": ""
            };

    var ft = new FileTransfer();
    ft.upload(imageURI, s3URI + "",
            win, fail, options);
}
function win(r) {
    console.log("Code = " + r.responseCode);
    console.log("Response = " + r.response);
    console.log("Sent = " + r.bytesSent);
    alert(r.response);
}
function fail(error) {
    alert("An error has occurred: Code = " + error.code);
}
```

Comment: if you are using the base64, why don't you just use a simple AJAX POST?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @jcesarmobile In my app its sometimes base64 while some times its jpg/png its conditions based, hence I opted for FileTransfer, it really works well at android side and ios side too for jpg/png

Comment: @Emre: I get the error, Error Code 1 which says file not found only for base64 ios, In Android it works perfectly fine for base64 and png/jpg and in ios also it works fine for jpg/png but for base64 it gives File Transfer failed with Error Code 1 which says file not found

Comment: @MayuriRuparel, How did you upload base64 image using cordova-plugin-file-transfer in Android? I'm [trying to do this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37063410/cant-upload-base64-image-using-cordova-plugin-file-transfer/37071410?noredirect=1#comment61690633_37071410) and it's not working :/

Answer (score 1):

Version 1.5.0 of the file transfer plugin has already added that functionality. The patch was applied 14 Dec 2015.

You can see the commit [here](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/commit/182b0c5ebebd8c0d313c676de0f92b8a56a81cb1).

Upgrading the plugin solved the problem in my case at least.

Answer (score 0):

Set chunkMode true when use base64 for upload using phonegap

Answer (score 0):

I set chunkMode true but still file is not transferring on server .It seems that cordova file transfer plugin does not support base64 image for upload on iOS.